# PostgreSQL delete and aggregate data periodically

Tags: postgresql, thingsboard

I'm developing a sensor monitoring application using Thingsboard CE and PostgreSQL.

**Contex**:
We collect data every second, such that we can have a real time view of the sensors measurements.
This however is very exhaustive on storage and does not constitute a requirement other than enabling real time monitoring. For example there is no need to check measurements made last week with such granularity (1 sec intervals), hence no need to keep such large volumes of data occupying resources. The average value for every 5 minutes would be perfectly fine when consulting the history for values from previous days.

**Question**:
This poses the question on how to delete existing rows from the database while aggregating the data being deleted and inserting a new row that would average the deleted data for a given interval. For example I would like to keep raw data (measurements every second) for the present day and aggregated data (average every 5 minutes) for the present month, etc.
What would be the best course of action to tackle this problem?

I checked to see if PostgreSQL had anything resembling this functionality but didn't find anything. My main ideia is to use a cron job to periodically perform the aggregations/deletions from raw data to aggregated data. Can anyone think of a better option? I very much welcome any suggestions and input.

**UPDATE**: I ended up using [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) a simple cron-based job scheduler for PostgreSQL. Very useful and simple to use, performs as one would expect!

Comment: I think a cron job is a very decent solution for your problem, inside the db you could create triggers for example without installing anything else, but I think this solution is not as good as the cron. Maybe you can take a look to this: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented similar using pg_agent. I have pgAdmin and pgagent running in separate containers to thingsboard. On a regular basis, i delete unneeded telemetry to keep backup size down and save disk space. I can configure ttl per entity by just adding a server attribute to the entity with ttl value. I like the semi-GUI based approach that pgagent / pgadmin provides.

I could see using this same functionality to aggregate data points.

If you prefer to push the aggregated data back to thingsboard via the api (possibly more supported method), I have found node-red to be perfect for this type of scenario.